# VBA Excel: Make header depend on filename

Tags: vba, excel, header, filenames

I've created a Macro that takes care of a document's lay-out, print properties, etc.
Now I'd like to add a way to make the header depend on the filename. If there is a W to be found in the filename, the header should read "Weekly report", in any other case it should be "Daily report".

Here's the chunk that should take care of that:

```
If Filename.Contains("W") Then GoTo Week Else GoTo Day
Week:
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
    .LeftHeader = "Weekly report"
    End With
GoTo JumpToThere
Day:
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
    .LeftHeader = "Daily report"
    End With
JumpToThere:
```

(then the code continues)

I keep getting a "Run-time error '424': Object required" error on the IF command.
Sorry to bother, I really don't know much about coding...

Comment: Is your file in Filename is Active workbook?

Comment: Yes. The code is stored in Personal but it concerns the workbook in focus.

Comment: Could you please show me the code where Filename is declared

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code doesn't include `Filename` declaration and assignment, but if it's a `string` then you should replace:

```
If Filename.Contains("W") Then
```

With

```
If Filename Like "*W*" Then
```

You can also simplify the logic in your `if` statement, and get rid of `GoTo`:

```
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
    If Filename Like "*W*" Then
      .LeftHeader = "Weekly report"
    Else
      .LeftHeader = "Daily report"
    End If
End With
```

EDIT:

There is no `Filename` property you could use out of the box. If you want to compare active workbook's name, you should use:

```
If ActiveWorkbook.Name Like "*W*" Then
```

Comment: This seems to work (no errors) but it keeps landing at "Daily report", even if the filename contains a "W". Do I still need to declare Filename in your sample without GoTo? If so, how? Mind that there are no definitions in this document, it's just plain code obtained by using the Record Macro function in Excel.

Comment: While I was waiting for a reply I started messing around myself and found something that works as well. I preceded the code with these lines:
    Dim Filename As String
    Filename = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @Timmmmaaahh just be careful with `FullName` as it includes full path, so the test might give false positive result if one of the folders contains `W`. `Name` contains only file name.

Comment: Awesome! I'm getting smarter by the minute on here ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have declared "Filename" and in "Filename" correct name is coming. And then Try like this -

```
If InStr(Filename, "W") > 0 Then GoTo Week Else GoTo Day
    Week:
        With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .LeftHeader = "Weekly report"
        End With
    GoTo JumpToThere
    Day:
        With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .LeftHeader = "Daily report"
        End With
    JumpToThere:
```